# What is the shelf life for DME?

Tags: ingredients, extract, malt, dme

I have a package of Briess Golden Light DME, and I noticed on the back it had a date stamp of 130923 10:57, which I assume to mean it was produced on Sept. 23, 2013.

It got me wondering if DME actually had a shelf life. How long will a sealed package of DME remain useful as a brewing ingredient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stored cool, dry and out of sunlight, DME is good for 2+ years. The main issue is with it picking up moisture, when it then becomes clumpy. But once boiled it's still good and you can use it up to 5 years in small quantities (say 1-2lb/0.5-1kg in a 5 gallon batch.)

Answer (score 2):

From the first item in the [search results for "briess dme shelf life":](https://www.google.com/search?q=briess+dme+shelf+life) [Briess "Product Information & Typical Analysis" sheet for a similar DME [PDF Warning]](http://www.brewingwithbriess.com/Assets/PDFs/Briess_PISB_CBWTradDarkDME.pdf)

```
STORAGE AND SHELF LIFE
Store in a cool, dry location.
Unopened bags best if used within 24 months from date of manufacture.
```

Comment: please don't post google searches. the results can change. It's better to post the link where you found the information.